# Appending existing xml_node into another one using pugixml

Tags: c++, xml-serialization, pugixml

How to append an exsiting `pugi::xml_node` into another one using pugixml ?
the only function that i know is :

```
pugi::xml_node node = root.append_child("child");
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use cloning functions described here:

http://pugixml.org/docs/manual.html#modify.clone

Note that cloning functions can't clone the entire document - i.e. if you have a document that's loaded from this data:

```
<node><child /></node>
```

Then if you want to clone this data into <child> node, you should do:

```
doc.child("node").child("child").append_copy(doc.child("node"));
```

This will yield the following document:

```
<node><child><node><child /></node></child></node>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found this methods as well: http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release-0.9/docs/manual/modify.html

```
xml_node xml_node::append_child(xml_node_type type = node_element);
xml_node xml_node::insert_child_after(xml_node_type type, const xml_node& node);
xml_node xml_node::insert_child_before(xml_node_type type, const xml_node& node);
```

> insert_child_after and insert_child_before add the (existing) node before or
>   after specified node/attribute.

Comment: Try xml_node xml_node::insert_child_after(xml_node_type type, const xml_node& node) please - it seems to be the same with append

Comment: That is node_element or node_document: both of them can contain the children

Comment: i only have pugi::xml_document with a root element and i want to append to this node some exsiting nodes, what to do ?

Comment: Take a look at this example, HTH: http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release-0.9/docs/manual/modify.html